# cocos2d-x(v3.14.1)のandroidで、sdkbox::PluginShare::init()時にクラッシュしてしまう

Tags: android, java, c++, twitter, cocos2d-x

#### 前提・実現したいこと

androidで、sdkboxのtwitterシェア機能（画像付き）を実装したいのですが、

android版のみ

```
sdkbox::PluginShare::init();
```

の部分でクラッシュしてしまいます。
iOSは問題なく動作しています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

下記logcatを拾ったエラーメッセージになります。
twitter以外にもfabricのcrashlytics(answersは計測できている)もエラーを吐いており、
両方とも正しく動作していないようです。

```

```
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.Crash$FatalException.<init>
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:174)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:251)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.Crash$FatalException.<init>
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.recordFatalExceptionEvent(CrashlyticsCore.java:715)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeFatal(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:808)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:278)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$100(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:55)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$5.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:254)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$5.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:251)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
E/CrashlyticsCore(13497):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13497): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.<init>:(Lcom/twitter/sdk/android/core/TwitterAuthConfig;)V from class com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter.<init>(Twitter.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at com.sdkbox.plugin.PluginShareTwitterConnector$1.run(PluginShareTwitterConnector.java:77)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5159)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:810)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:577)
E/AndroidRuntime(13497):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```

#### 該当のソースコード

proj.android-studio/app/build.gradle

```

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {

    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hogehogehogehoge"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4096M"
        jumboMode = true
        preDexLibraries = false
    }


    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDir "src"
        res.srcDir "res"
        jniLibs.srcDir "libs"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        assets.srcDir "assets"
    }
    signingConfigs {
       release {
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }


    configurations {
      all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }


}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libcocos2dx')

    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:+@aar') { 
      transitive = true; exclude module: 'support-v4' 
    }

    compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.15.0'){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'; 
    }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10@aar') {
      transitive = true; exclude module: 'fabric'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
      transitive = true; exclude module: 'fabric'
    }

    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```

その他のbuild.gradleファイル

```

```
$ find ./ | grep build.gradle
.//cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/libs/gps/build.gradle
.//cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/libcocos2dx/build.gradle
.//cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/libcocos2dx/libs/facebook_lib/build.gradle
.//cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/libcocos2dx-with-controller/build.gradle
.//proj.android-studio/app/build.gradle
.//proj.android-studio/build.gradle
```

```

proj.android-studio/app/src/org/cocos2dx/cpp/AppActivity.java

```

```
package org.cocos2dx.cpp;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.Crash;
import jp.hogehelper.ad.AdMob;
import jp.hogehelper.ad.Facebook;
import jp.hogehelper.ad.Nend;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;


import java.util.Locale;

public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity {

private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
      // Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
      //private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "aaaaaaaaaa";
      //private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "bbbbbbbb";

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      /*
      TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
      Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
      */

      Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
      Fabric.with(this, new Answers());

      mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

    }
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      AdMob.getInstance().onResume();
      Facebook.getInstance().onResume();
      Nend.getInstance().onResume();
      AdMobVideo.getInstance().onResume();
    }    @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    AdMob.getInstance().onPause();
    Facebook.getInstance().onPause();
    Nend.getInstance().onPause();
    AdMobVideo.getInstance().onPause();
    super.onPause();
  }    @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    AdMob.getInstance().onDestroy();
    //Facebook.getInstance().onDestroy();
    Nend.getInstance().onDestroy();
    AdMobVideo.getInstance().onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
  }


  /**
   * @return current language.
   */
  public static String getCurrentLanguage() {
    if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("zh")) {
      return Locale.getDefault().toString();
    }
    return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
  }
  /** * @return true if need reset review app state.
   */
  public static boolean isNeedResetReviewAppState() {
    try {
      String currentAppVersion = Cocos2dxActivity.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(Cocos2dxActivity.getContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
      String previousVersion = SharePrefs.getInstance().getAppVersion();
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(previousVersion)) {
        // first launch
        SharePrefs.getInstance().setAppVersion(currentAppVersion);
        return true;
      } else if (previousVersion.equals(currentAppVersion)){
        // same version
      }else{
        // other version
        SharePrefs.getInstance().setAppVersion(currentAppVersion);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
  }


}
```

```

proj.android-studio/app/src/org/cocos2dx/cpp/MultiDexHogeApplication.java

```

```
package org.cocos2dx.cpp;

import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

import com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import android.util.Log;


public class MultiDexHogeApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

Log.d("tag_name", "soccerr   ______debuglog text");

       FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
       AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
       AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(this);

        SharePrefs.getInstance().init(this);
    }


}
```

```

Class/AppDelegate.cpp

```

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "AppInitialize.hpp"
#include "SceneTop.hpp"
#include "SceneOpening.hpp"
#include <cocos2d.h>
#include "PluginGoogleAnalytics/PluginGoogleAnalytics.h" //sdkboxで入れたgoogleAnalytics
#include "PluginAdMob/PluginAdMob.h"
//#include "PluginFacebook/PluginFacebook.h"
#include <PluginShare/PluginShare.h>
//#include "PluginShare/PluginShare.h"

#include "AdMobHelper.hpp"
#include "AdMobManager.hpp" //admob周り全体を管理するもの

//#import <Firebase.h>
//#import <Answers/Answers.h>
//#import <Google/Analytics.h>
//#include "AdTest.hpp"


using namespace cocos2d;

AppDelegate::AppDelegate() {}

AppDelegate::~AppDelegate() {}

// if you want a different context,just modify the value of glContextAttrs
// it will takes effect on all platforms
void AppDelegate::initGLContextAttrs() {
    // set OpenGL context attributions,now can only set six attributions:
    // red,green,blue,alpha,depth,stencil

#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS
    GLContextAttrs glContextAttrs = {8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8};
#elif CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
    GLContextAttrs glContextAttrs = {5, 6, 5, 0, 16, 8};
#endif

    GLView::setGLContextAttrs(glContextAttrs);
}

static int register_all_packages() {
    return 0;  // flag for packages manager
}

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {




    // initialize director
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
    if (!glview) {
        glview = GLViewImpl::create("paz");
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }

    // set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
    director->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);

    // FPS表示   // turn on display FPS
//    director->setDisplayStats(true);

    // Set the design resolution
    glview->setDesignResolutionSize(SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H,
                                    ResolutionPolicy::EXACT_FIT);

    register_all_packages();

    // run
    director->runWithScene(AppInitialize::create());


    // share
    //sdkbox::PluginShare::init();
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS
    // share
    sdkbox::PluginShare::init();
#elif CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
    // TODO androidだと落ちる
    sdkbox::PluginShare::init();
#endif

    // sdkbox: google analytics初期化
    sdkbox::PluginGoogleAnalytics::init();
    sdkbox::PluginGoogleAnalytics::startSession();

    return true;
}

void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    Director::getInstance()->stopAnimation();

    // if you use SimpleAudioEngine, it must be pause
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
}

void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    Director::getInstance()->startAnimation();

    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
}
```

```

#### 試したこと

- google-play-services or supportv4周りの重複ライブラリを除去や、バージョン一致
- fabric(answers/crashlytics)との衝突回避
- とにかく、関係がありそうなライブラリを消したり足したり。汗
- sdkbox::PluginShare::init()一度も呼ばずに、sdkbox::PluginShare::share(info);をしても落ちはしない。

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

- cocos2d-x version3.14.1
- mac OSX 10.11.6
- xcode 8.21
- 計測＆広告周りのSDKが沢山入っています。

Answer (score 1):

こちら、sdkboxのpluginシェア機能をつかわず、androidの場合のみ、ネイティブなjavaのコードでシェア機能を実装しました。
androidOS6以降のパーミッションチェック等も手間でしたが、無事解決しました。
ご協力ありがとうございました！m( _ _ )m